# Check for multiple replace strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to make a script that edits a url.

This currently works

```js
jQuery(".int-tooltip a").attr("href", (_, href) =>
href.replace("/zh-hant/", "/") );
```

But how do I add multiple options besides "/zh-hant/"? Such as "/de/" or others to check and replace them with "/"?

Comment: What is the structure of your URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add multiple options to the replace method, you can use a regular expression with the | character, which represents a logical OR.

```
jQuery(".int-tooltip a").attr("href", (_, href) =>
href.replace(/\/zh-hant\/|\/de\/|\/other-option\//, "/") );
```